# TFS reports on daily basis

Tags: tfs, burndowncharts, tfs-reports

My team is using TFS 2008 and Conchango template for Scrum. We use the Sprint burndown chart, sprint view and sprint task board reports to track the status of tasks on daily basis. The burndown chart and sprint view are also shown on a LCD TV screen. These reports are manualy exported daily as PDF files.

Is there any utility which can pull the reports daily at scheduled interval and export them as pdf?

Answer (score 1):

If the reports are available in the report server, all you need to do is create a subscription.

1. Go to the report server (e.g. `http://tfs/reports`)
2. Find your report and click on it to run it once.
3. Click on the "Subscriptions" tab.

Fill out the details, and you should be good to go.

If the reports are only available in the VS IDE, you might need to re-create them in SSRS.

Comment: Is there any way while susbscribing to subscribe to the latest sprint reports? I haven't tried your suggestion but the reports are available over the report server. If there is no way to subscribe to the current sprint and if your suggestion works it might save me atleast daily routine during a sprint. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: Not sure, as we're not using the scrum template right now.  I think you can specify input parameters, though.  Give it a shot!

Comment: I can't see the subscribe option when I run the report. Is this option available only for the user with Admin previllages?